# JFreeChart - IntervalMarker vertical?

Tags: java, jfreechart, markers, marker

In the examples provided by `JFreechart`, we see that it is possible to display horizontal `IntervalMarker`s. I would like to build vertical `IntervalMarker`s and I do not find the way to do that using this [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartXYSeriesDemo3.htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Cartesian coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system) , the [domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function) is orthogonal to the [range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_%28mathematics%29), so

```
final IntervalMarker target = new IntervalMarker(10.0, 20.0);
target.setLabel("Target Domain");
...
plot.addDomainMarker(target, Layer.BACKGROUND);
```